# How many characters from Derek Hales family do we know exist (dead and living)?

Tags: object-identification, teen-wolf

In Teen Wolf Derek Hale's whole family was either ripped in half, burnt or off hiding, not counting Peter and Malia. Does anyone know any other members of his family, could you name them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to give anyone answering this question something to go on, just fill in where I left off.

1. Talia: His mother. Dead. Died in the Hale fire. She was alpha.
2. Laura: his older sister. Dead. Died in mid-season 1.
3. **Cora**: his younger sister. Alive. Living in South America.
4. **Peter**: his uncle. Alive. Killed his sister Laura, was living in a hospital with his body burnt, but healed in Season 1.
5. **Malia**: Possibly his niece (Peter's daughter). Alive. I say possibly because I don't know if Peter is lying or not.

That's all I know, and yes, I used the wiki and watched the show.